# Annotation Processor: How to know if a Kotlin class is marked with “internal” visibility modifier from Element

Tags: kotlin, annotation-processing, annotation-processor

I'm using [Auto Service](https://github.com/google/auto/tree/master/service) to process some annotations but I'm unable to identify if a Kotlin class has the "internal" visibility modifier from the Annotation Processor API.

I'm using KAPT and Kotlin in the processor. Dependencies:

```
    implementation group: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin', name: 'kotlin-reflect', version: "1.3.0-rc-190"
    implementation files("${System.properties['java.home']}/../lib/tools.jar")
    implementation 'com.squareup:kotlinpoet:1.0.0-RC2'
    implementation "com.google.auto.service:auto-service:1.0-rc4"
    kapt "com.google.auto.service:auto-service:1.0-rc4"
```

Sample Class:

```
@MyAnnotation
internal class Car
```

I got the TypeElement of this inside the process method

```
override fun process(annotations: MutableSet<out TypeElement>, roundEnv: RoundEnvironment): Boolean {
        roundEnv.getElementsAnnotatedWith(MyAnnotation::class.java).forEach { classElement ->
            if (classElement.kind != ElementKind.CLASS) {
                error(...)
                return true
            }
            classElement as TypeElement
```

But I don't know how to detect if the class has the "internal" modifier.

If I do: `classElement.modifiers` I get this:
[image]

Any idea on how to detect the "internal" modifier?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When your Kotlin code converted to the `.class` form there is no `internal` modifier. But when you decompile your `.class` files of your Kotlin code you see that there is a `@Metadata` annotation.

This [metadata](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-metadata/index.html) annotation gives you some information about Kotlin declarations in the binary form. You can use [Kotlinx-metadata](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/tree/master/libraries/kotlinx-metadata/jvm) to read and modify metadata of `.class` files.

So, what you need is to get `@Metadata` annotation from `classElement` and then use Flags from `kotlinx-metadata` to find out if it has internal modifier or not:

for example:

```
override fun visitFunction(flags: Flags, name: String): KmFunctionVisitor? {
    if (Flag.IS_INTERNAL(flags)) {
        println("function $name is internal")
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It works! Do you know if there is an easy way to parse classElement.metadata into the params required the `KotlinClassHeader`? I'm doing this manually but it's really error prone.

Comment: Hmm, well I don't see any another way. Actually, annotation processing is a hard thing and annotation processing with Kotlin metadata parsing is a harder thing. So, It can be really error-prone but make sure to write enough tests =)